# that he should fail

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives

Can one say

A. The worst that can happen is for him to fail the exam.

B. The worst that can happen is that he should fail the exam.

C. The worst that can happen is that he can fail the exam.

D. The worst that can happen is that he fails the exam.

?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

All of them can technically be said, but C is awkward because of the second "Can,"
and B sounds a bit like he is supposed to fail.

A and C are the best and most natural sounding. You could also say

"The worst that can happen to him is failing the exam"

Answer (score 1):

My money's on D.

The others have unnecessary prepositions.  In fact a native English speaker would probably understand all of these sentences to mean the same thing in casual conversation but, if you want to be pedantic, A, B and C mean different things:

- A. means that him failing the exam is the reason why the worst can
  happen.
- B. means that the worst that can happen is that it would be
  preferable for him to fail.
- C. means that the worst that can happen
  is that he has the ability to fail.